# Can "all about and about" be a substitute for "all about the same"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it OK to say "Other girls besides you are **all about and about**" instead of "Other girls besides you are **all about the same**"?

What I mean is "There's no one else better than you because all other girls have nothing on you." I would like to say "너 외에 다른 여자는 다 거기서 거기다" (A Korean expression) in English.

An English dictionary says "The candidates are **all about and about**," is "후보들은 모두 비슷비슷하다." And "거기서 거기다" can mean "비슷하다"(*to be* similar).
In the literal sense, "거기서 거기" is "from there to there" or "nothing further/better/harder from there." Because "거기" is used twice in the expression, I thought using "about" twice could transfer the meaning well. If "all about and about" isn't a good choice, I don't know what would be better.

Comment: I would vote no. I've not seen this phrasing before, and I can't see how it maps to the meaning you are striving to communicate.

Comment: I concur. Is this perhaps a literal translation of an idiom in your own language? If so, could you add that idiom to your question, for our guidance and edification? :)

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, you're right. I edited my question just now. I'm asking this because there are not enough Google search results about "about and about."

Comment: @Krypt "About and about" is not an English idiom.

Comment: @StoneyB Then, I guess I should not use that dictionary. "Neither here nor there" would go well with the sense but I'd better find other expressions.

Answer (score 1):

We have an expression in English: *neither here nor there*. It means *irrelevant, of no concern*

> His argument against this is neither here nor there.
>   Whether you like him is neither here nor there.

It might be used in approximately the sense you describe.

> Sure other girls are attractive, but that's neither here nor there. It's you I care about.

But it's not exactly the same.

Comment: What about using "much of a muchness"? I've found it refers to "Of two or more things, having little difference of any significance between them."